# Filtering 50Hz using a notch filter in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, filters

I've read up a lot about this, but haven't been able to piece everything together successfully, so I'm looking for some help.

I need to filter 50 Hz from a signal. It looks like the best options are either a notch filter or a LMS filter, but I don't have a copy of the noise so a notch filter seems to be the best choice.

I don't need the frequencies normalised, as I know the sampling frequency (16kHz), and the duration is 30 seconds. The bandwidth can be fairly tight, 49.5Hz ~ 50.5Hz should be fine.

It looks like I need to use a combination of `filter` and `iirnotch`, but I'm not entirely sure how.

If someone can bring this all together I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: I want to ask how the autoregressive filter simulation on damping/redaman???

Comment: How to define 'x' in above program (where 'x' is a signal input)... thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm not sure what iirnotch does, but this is how to design the notch filter by hand.

```
fs = 20000;             % sampling rate
f0 = 50;                % notch frequency
fn = fs/2;              % Nyquist frequency
freqRatio = f0/fn;      % ratio of notch freq. to Nyquist freq.

notchWidth = 0.1;       % width of the notch

% Compute zeros
notchZeros = [exp( sqrt(-1)*pi*freqRatio ), exp( -sqrt(-1)*pi*freqRatio )];

% Compute poles
notchPoles = (1-notchWidth) * notchZeros;

figure;
zplane(notchZeros.', notchPoles.');

b = poly( notchZeros ); %  Get moving average filter coefficients
a = poly( notchPoles ); %  Get autoregressive filter coefficients

figure;
freqz(b,a,32000,fs)

% filter signal x
y = filter(b,a,x);
```

Comment: Simple and elegant. I understand that the smaller notchWidth, the smaller the width of the notch will be, but does notchWidth relate to a concrete quantity?

Comment: @Lolo I don't think it does. I just picked it because it seemed like a convenient number.

Answer (score 9):

You can just type help iirnotch and then see the following example:

```
% Design a filter with a Q-factor of Q=35 to remove a 60 Hz tone from 
% system running at 300 Hz.
Wo = 60/(300/2);  BW = Wo/35;
[b,a] = iirnotch(Wo,BW);
```

If you replace the 60 with 50 Hz and then do:

```
Y = filter(b,a,X)
```

It should work (with X your data)